# Retorno dos atributos na Model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Tenho uma aplicação onde as subcategorias são associadas a uma categoria.

No Model da Subcategoria é realizado o relacionamento entre ambos e retornado o nome da categoria através do getAttribute, onde retorno o nome da categoria. O problema é que além do nome da subcategoria, são retornadas todas as informações da categoria.

A model da **Subcategoria** está assim:

```
class Subcategoria extends Model
{

protected $table = 'subcategoria';
protected $keyType = 'integer';
protected $fillable = ['id_categoria', 'nome'];
protected $appends = ['links', 'anexos'];

public function categoria()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'id_categoria');
}

public function produto()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Produto::class, 'id_subcategoria');
}

public function getLinksAttribute () : array
{
    return [
        'self' => '/api/v1/subcategoria/' . $this->id,
        'categoria' => '/api/v1/categoria/' . $this->id_categoria,
    ];
}

public function getAnexosAttribute() : array
{
    return [
        'categoria' => $this->categoria->nome,
    ];
}
}
```

A Model da **Categoria**:

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
protected $table = 'categoria';
protected $keyType = 'integer';
protected $fillable = ['nome'];
protected $appends = ['links'];

public function produto()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Produto::class, 'id_categoria');
}

public function subcategoria()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subcategoria::class, 'id_categoria');
}

public function getLinksAttribute()
{
    return [
        'self' => '/api/v1/categoria/' . $this->id,
        'subcategorias' => '/api/v1/categoria/' . $this->id . '/subcategorias'
    ];
}
}
```

O retorno é o seguinte:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Chocolate",
    "id_categoria": 13,
    "created_at": "2019-09-16 17:27:51",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-23 12:59:34",
    "links": {
        "self": "/api/v1/subcategoria/1",
        "categoria": "/api/v1/categoria/13"
    },
    "anexos": {
        "categoria": "Alimentos"
    },
    "categoria": {
        "id": 13,
        "nome": "Alimentos",
        "created_at": "2019-09-19 19:59:06",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-19 19:59:15",
        "links": {
            "self": "/api/v1/categoria/13",
            "subcategorias": "/api/v1/categoria/13/subcategorias"
        }
    }
},
"status": true
}
```

E eu gostaria que fosse apenas:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Chocolate",
    "id_categoria": 13,
    "created_at": "2019-09-16 17:27:51",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-23 12:59:34",
    "links": {
        "self": "/api/v1/subcategoria/1",
        "categoria": "/api/v1/categoria/13"
    },
    "anexos": {
        "categoria": "Alimentos"
    }
},
"status": true
}
```

> Alguém sabe o que é necessário fazer para chegar ao resultado
>   desejado?

Comment: Uma opção que eu utilizo muito é dar um map() após o get() e retornar apenas os campos que eu desejo. Fica tipo `$listaItens = Subcategoria::where(xyz)->get()->map(function() { return ['campo1' => 'valor', 'campo2' => 'valor'] });`. Deve haver outras formas de omitir os campos.

Comment: Cara isso tu pode usar o Fractal para a resposta ser somente o que você quer ou usar o GraphQL. Usando o fractal: https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta com o código que você usa para gerar os JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido apenas adicionando a variável hidden à Model:

```
protected $hidden = ['categoria'];
```